# DaoAuthenticationProvider not getting invoked

Tags: database, spring, rest, spring-boot, authentication

I am trying to authenticate a request from using spring security, I have followed few blogs and videos but i am not able to fix the issues. 
Security configuration is loaded but my requests are not getting authenticated. I get 403 error

Bean class in WebSecurityConfigureAdapter

```
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        System.out.println(userDetailsService());
        return authProvider; 
    }
```

over riding configure method

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/products","/orders").hasAnyRole("admin");//.authenticated(); 

    }
```

```
user details services overridding loadUserByUsername  
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String loginName) {

        String authenticated = "false";

        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        List<Users> usersList = usersRepository.findByLoginName(loginName);
        if(usersList.size()==0) {
            return null;
        }else {

            for (Users users : usersList) {
                List<Roles> rolesList = users.getRoles();
                for (Roles roles : rolesList) {

                    if(roles.getUserRole().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
                        authenticated = "admin"; 
                        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authenticated);
                        User user = new User(users.getLoginName(),users.getPassword(),Arrays.asList(authority));
                        userDetails = (UserDetails)user; 
                    }       
                }
            }
            return userDetails;
        }
```

using postman setting up the credentials as basicAuth, its throwing 403 error

Answer (score 0):

the issue was...
we need to either set the value for different getters in userdetails class or explicitly set to true
i have below getters explicitly set it to true, it worked for me

```
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
```